# What is this finger style strumming called?

Tags: guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, strumming

I am learning guitar from last 2-3 months and i am just curious to know what is this [Bailamos (Guitar Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCrHQb4BFVQ) finger style strumming technique is called?

Answer (score 2):

The name for this technique is *[rasgueado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasgueado)*.